# IF AND OR Formula in Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I'm unable to use the below formula in Simple Query is MS Access while the same can be used in MS Excel and i'm getting a syntax error in which i'm unable to figure out the error.

SUSPENSION DATE: IIF ( OR ( LEFT ( [CUSTOMER_SEGMENT] , 2) = "IP", LEFT ( [CUSTOMER_SEGMENT] , 2 ) = "IT", LEFT ( [CUSTOMER_SEGMENT] , 2)="ID"), [BILLDATE] + 55 , IIF ( Or ( LEFT ( [CUSTOMER_SEGMENT] , 2)="IG", LEFT ( [CUSTOMER_SEGMENT] , 2)="IS"), [BILLDATE] + 55 , IIF ( And ( OR ( [BARRING_SERVICE] = "A" , [BARRING_SERVICE] = "B" ), [AGE_ON_NETWORK] > = 12 ), [BILLDATE] + 55 , IIF ( AND ( OR (  [BARRING_SERVICE] = "C" , [BARRING_SERVICE] ="D" ), [AGE_ON_NETWORK] > = 12 ), [BILLDATE] + 40 , IIF ( AND ( [AGE_ON_NETWORK] > = 5, [AGE_ON_NETWORK] < = 11 ) , [BILLDATE] + 34 , [BILLDATE] + 29 )))))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `OR()` *function* is an Excel construct that Access does not support. Access uses an `OR` *operator* instead. So in Excel where you would use

```
IF(OR(Condition1, Condition2), ValueIfTrue, ValueIfFalse)
```

in Access you would use

```
IIf(Condition1 OR Condition2, ValueIfTrue, ValueIfFalse)
```

Answer (score 2):

That's quite a monster of a nested IIF.

Since the first part of what you want to do is calculate the `SUSPENSION_DATES` in relation to the `CUSTOMER_SEGMENT` you should simply add a column `SEGMENT_GROUP` to the `CUSTOMER_SEGMENT` table (if exists) and create a table in which you map the `SEGMENT_GROUP` to the `SUSPENSION_IN_DAYS`, i.e. the number of days which you want to add to the `BILLDATE`.

```
CUSTOMER_SEGMENT SEGMENT_GROUP
IT_Foo           IT
IT_Bar           IT
ID_Else          ID
...

SEGMENT_GROUP   SUSPENSION_IN_DAYS
IT              55
ID              55
...
```

It will be easier to maintain if ever these values change and you can get the first part of your IIF by Join.